# How can I get name of the Feign client?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I have simple interface:

```
public interface ServiceClient {
  String REFRESH_ENDPOINT = "/admin/refresh";
  ResponseEntity<String> refresh();
}
```

and few FeignClients like this:

```
@FeignClient(name = "${ServiceA.name}", configuration = 
FeignConfiguration.class, decode404 = true)
public interface ServiceA extends ServiceClient {

  @PostMapping(path = REFRESH_ENDPOINT)
  ResponseEntity<String> refresh();
}
```

Then I do:

```
private final List<ServiceClient> services;
...
services.parallelStream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(s-> s.getClass().getName(), s-> s.refresh().getStatusCode()));
```

How I can get name of the Feign client? `getClass().getName()` gives me `Proxy154`. I would prefer to not create static field in every FeignClient I have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use AopProxyUtils.

```
services.parallelStream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(s-> 
                  AopProxyUtils.proxiedUserInterfaces(greetingClient)[0].getName(), 
                  s-> s.refresh().getStatusCode()));
```

Not sure if you want the class name or the name you have in `@FeignClient` annotation. If you want the name in Annotation, then you can get it like this

```
Class<?>[] classes = AopProxyUtils.proxiedUserInterfaces(greetingClient);
FeignClient annotation = classes[0].getAnnotation(FeignClient.class);
System.out.println(annotation.name());
```

Comment: Didn't work. Still getting `{"com.sun.proxy.$Proxy154"="OK", "com.sun.proxy.$Proxy155"="OK", "com.sun.proxy.$Proxy156"="OK"}`

Comment: Both "Edit" solutions resulting with:
`java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy155 cannot be cast to org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised`

Comment: edited my answer checkout. Not sure if you want the class name or the name in the annotation of `@FeignClient`

Comment: It is closer now;-) But it still gives: `${ServiceA.name}`. So we need to extract propertyKey, I mean `"ServiceA.name"` and use `env.getProperty("ServiceA.name")`